# Swift Playgrounds on iPad Not Working with SwiftUI code as Expected

Tags: swiftui, swift-playground

The attached code works as expected on the Playgrounds simulator for the Mac but the States don't register a view update when the same code runs on an iPad.  Does anyone know of a known issue/fix/workaround?

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct MathGame: View
{
    @State var showAnswer = false
    @State var answer = ""
    @State var x = Int.random(in: 0...100)
    @State var y = Int.random(in: 0...100)
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            Text(x.description)
            Text(y.description)
            if showAnswer
            {
                let z = x + y
                Text(z.description)
            } else
            {
                Text(" ")
            }

            
            Button("Next Question")
                {
                showAnswer = false
                x = Int.random(in: 0...100)
                y = Int.random(in: 0...100)
            }
            Spacer()
            Toggle(isOn: $showAnswer)
            {
                Text("Show Answer")
            } 
        }.padding().font(.system(size: 64))
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(MathGame())
```

Comment: What does not work here? Could you provide more details?

Comment: Sorry about that.  When one clicks on Show Answer, nothing changes (the answer is not shown).  It is as if the toggle does not register but you can see the toggle is on but the answer remains blank.

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1. Which versions do you use?

Comment: Running on iPad/Playgrounds 3.4,Swift 5.3, iOS 14.3,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue and I just found out that setting « Show results » to false was fixing it.

[image]

My iPad runs on iOS 14.6. I hope that the new Swift playgrounds with iOS 15 will fix this issue definitely.